# Create dockerfile dotnet api

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile

Good morning,

I want to create a dockerfile that contains a dotnet and clamav api to do a virus scan when I send my file to my api

J'ai donc le fichier suivant :

```
    #See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base

# Installer ClamAV
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y clamav clamav-daemon

# Créer le répertoire pour le socket local
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/clamav/

# Copier le contenu du fichier clamd.conf directement dans le Dockerfile
RUN echo "LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl" > /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
RUN echo "TCPSocket 3310" >> /etc/clamav/clamd.conf

# Copier le contenu du fichier clamd.conf directement dans le Dockerfile
RUN echo "LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl" > /etc/clamav/clamd.conf

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 3310

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="none"
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="none"
ARG AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="none"
ARG AWS_REGION="eu-west-3"

WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y jq 
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install

RUN aws sts get-caller-identity
RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --repository qvmd-dev-nuget --domain qvmd-dev --region eu-west-3

COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# Démarrer le service ClamAV
CMD ["service", "clamav-daemon", "start"]


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll", "--urls", "http://+:5000"]
```

and when my api has to call clamav I have a connection refused error. I call localhost on port 3310.